# What's a good statistical test for the following data

Tags: statistical-significance, t-test

I have a dataset that looks like this:
[image]

This is a sample dataset from a medical practice.  Codes are used to bill insurance companies for the services provided to the patients by the providers.  Expected revenue is the income that the medical practice has expected to receive from the number of patients and the Medicare allowable rate (maximum amount Medicare pays for a particular code). Reimbursement revenue is the actual revenue that they have received.

I want to test if the difference between the expected revenue and the reimbursement revenue is statistically significant for each code using the independent t-test.    But the problem is I have 75 insurance codes.  I would like to know if there is any test that will let me test all 75 codes at once or if I have to run 75 independent t-tests.
Thanks!

Comment: I am not sure how you are planning on running a t-test on these results. Comparing the reimbursement to expected without some an understanding of variability is not a valid test. Maybe if you look at a histogram of Reimbursement/Expected you can gain an understanding of which codes are underpaying.

Comment: @Dave2e  At a glance, I thought of using the independent t-test but now I realize the issue with the variances.  Thank You!

Comment: From an accounting point of view, any billed amount that does not equal the amount payed is a discrepancy that requires an explanation. Without listing the individual billing numbers and their corresponding amounts paid, the totals of many such bills/reimbursements have little chance of agreement.